# Is there a ruling on saying the name of Allah whilst looking at something

Tags: shirk, waswasa

I have these really weird waswas when I doing dua/dhikr and saying the name of Allah that whatever I'm looking at I'm saying that's Allah. I think I'm doing shirk and this happens everyday.

For example if I say "Ya Allah" and am looking at some object I get these waswas which say I'm saying that object is Allah.

Answer (score 0):

Inshallah no because the prophet (pbwh) said

> Al-Bukhaari (5269) and Muslim (127) also narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it.”

So inshallah as long as you don't act upon it's okey

Comment: But the thing is sometimes I've already said it whilst looking at an object. A few months I didn't have this problem and topics like shirk didn't even cross my mind. Now I think I've done shirk daily.

Comment: Look brother the way i know inshallah its not shirk is that you dont belive it, you have waswasa only but no internel belife that god is the object you are looking at. And if you still have doubt that it was shirk you can always revert again to islam and pray for forgivnes, may allah forgive you and all of us

Answer (score 0):

This dua is helpful to avoid bad thoughts, waswas **Rabbighfir Warham Wa Anta Khairur Rahemeen** This dua is mentioned in surah Al-Mu'minun(118 verse)
Repeat it many and many.
And also repeat thousands of **La ilaha illallah**
This was practiced.